# Where's the settings/preferences in Cheese photo booth?

Tags: webcam, cheese

My built in camera doesn't work well, it's damage and have crappy and blurry result, so I use a Logitech webcam.
Since I can switch the cams in Skype, I think the same option should be there for Cheese.

I have seen some threads saying to change the cam in Cheese settings, and this is a very stupid question but my Cheese has no settings/preferences or even a menu bar ; just the x, maximize and minimize window, the effects and take photo button.

Where do I access the settings or preferences?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to move your mouse to the upper left corner of your screen to reveal the Cheese Menu:

[image]

Then open the Preferences to select your device:

[image]

Comment: Worked, thanks. This is so absurd, why does every program has it's menu bar not sticking to the program window in Ubuntu? :s Even with firefox, I just realized the menu bar isn't where it should be but at the top of desktop screen.
Morever when you are in fullscreen, the menu bar doesn't come in view even on hover

Comment: @shahabuddin: You can choose the behavior of the global menu in 14.10, open the System Settings->Appearance->Behavior->Show the menus for a window.

Comment: @shahabuddin this is called "global menu". It has been one of the most discussed "features" of the gnome-based interfaces... either Unity or gnome-shell. It's a kind of holy war, really.

Comment: @Rmano: Being knew to the community, I have no idea what the debate is about but all I know is that having a global menu sticking outside the mainwindow of program by default is a really absurd idea.

Comment: @shahabuddin --- I don't like it either, but it's a matter of personal preferences. Macintosh-type OSes have it since time immemorial, and I think Ubuntu was inspired by that. But that is the good thing about the Linux systems --- you have choice.

Comment: Omg, it really works. So weird though.

Comment: Doesn't work if you have pointer-focus lol. As soon as you move out of the Cheese window to access the menu, the menu changes :-)
And, in Ubuntu 18.04, the global menu behavior setting has moved. It's now under gnome-tweaks/Top Bar/Application Menu. Turn that off and you get the menu on the window title bar phew.