# Setting camera for cheese from command line

Tags: webcam, cheese

I've got cheese (3.18.1) running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.   However, when I run it, there are no preferences.

In theory, when you run it, the camera can be set via preferences, as described here:

[Where's the settings/preferences in Cheese photo booth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591800/wheres-the-settings-preferences-in-cheese-photo-booth)

However, sometimes (like in my situation), the preferences menu doesn't drop down.  There is a workaround, but it isn't ideal:

[Gnome Cheese settings/prefs menu is missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133058/gnome-cheese-settings-prefs-menu-is-missing)

What about starting cheese from the command line?  Does anyone have an example of how to select the device?  I've tried the device number (from lsusb) and name, but all I get is a segmentation fault, so I guess I'm doing something wrong. For example, this:

cheese --device "USB camera"

Any thoughts?  Yeah, there is guvcview, but in a lot of systems, cheese is installed by default, and I'd figure it would be useful to know this way of specifying the camera.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the device ID instead of a name? lsusb and get the ID, for example - 046d:082c

Comment: Providing device name does not work; i.e.: cheese --device=046d:082c; gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: Check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133058/gnome-cheese-settings-prefs-menu-is-missing, now there is a way to do this with GUI (just like how old Cheese worked), and without `dconf-editor`.